# Play an audio file through my mic output

Tags: audio, microphone, audio-streaming

When I'm in a VoIP call with somebody, occasionally I have an audio file I want that person to hear. So I want to play the audio file to my mic output (so the caller hears the sound file as if it was coming from my mic). How do I do that?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This is lacking details. So you are making the VoIP call from your computer? What app are you using to make the call? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: The app shouldn't matter, I'm just trying to pass an audio file to my mic output (instead of my speaker output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a partial answer. I was looking for just a single shell command I could use (something like `pactl play-as-input rhythmbox ~/File.mp3`) but there doesn't appear to be anything that simple. However, I did find out that  `paprefs` allows you to setup what is called an RTP in order to switch certain programs to both input and output audio, so that's sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into JACK and QJackCtl, these are the command line and GUI interface that allow you to route your audio sources to any output of your desire.  This includes sending the audio over VOIP connections.

Comment: Can I install JACK without it interfering with PulseAudio in 16.04?